# why can't I get a title on a Pandas histogram?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Before you mark this question as answered, I've tried several other solutions and they're not working.

I'm doing the following in Spyder, Python 3.7.1, pandas 0.23.4, matplotlib 3.0.2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

(some other code to build the dataframe)
shoot_merge['population'].plot.hist(bins=30, figsize=(12,8), grid=True)
```

Ok, fine so far. It prints to screen. It has the y-label as "Frequency", but I need a title and x-label.

Other solutions look like this, and they probably work in Jupyter but I'm doing in Spyder. I've tried several solutions for pandas, matplotlib, and Seaborn and none of them are working for me. Like this:

```
gg = shoot_merge['population'].plot.hist(bins=30, figsize=(12,8), grid=True)
gg.set_xlabel("what the hell")
gg.set_title("Histogram of shootings by population")
```

And I get this output, but it doesn't print to screen:

```
gg.set_xlabel("what the hell")
Out[169]: Text(0.5, 3.200000000000003, 'what the hell')

gg.set_title("Histogram of shootings by population")
Out[170]: Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Histogram of shootings by population')

gg
Out[172]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1da041aa8d0>
```

I get that "gg" is a matplotlib object, so where is the plot?

I like Python but defining graphs is painful.

Comment: No, I said I'm doing in Spyder, not Jupyter. But I would probably save time if I just used Jupyter.

Comment: Are you writing those commands into the IPython console within Spyder? What are your Spyder settings concerning matplotlib? If you are using IPython's inline backend, and you want to show the figure again after making changes to it you need to state the figure, in your case `gg.figure`. (I would recommend to use `ax` instead of `gg`, to be consistent with all documentation and Q&As here).

Comment: Ah, I see it now....gg.figure. Thanks!

Comment: And it has the labels. Great.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

gg = shoot_merge['population'].plot.hist(bins=30, figsize=(12,8), grid=True)
gg.set_xlabel("what the hell")
gg.set_title("Histogram of shootings by population")
plt.show()
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

answered by ImportanceofbeingErnest